# Custom creation of cells in a LWUIT Table in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to create a LWUIT Table in my J2ME application where all cells in one column are of a particular type e.g. TextField taking decimal input.

Could anyone please suggest of achieving this or even another approach I could take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong area.

Instead of using `ListCellRenderer` I extended the Table object and overrode the `createCell` method.

```
public class CustomTable extends Table{
    public CustomTable(TableModel model) {
        super(model);
    }
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
        switch (column) {
            case QUANITY_COLUMN:
                // create custom cell and return
                ...
            default:
                return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you suggest any thing on how to add a click or selection lister for a row in the table?